# stripping tags from excerpt in Wordpress is not working

Tags: php, permalinks, tags, excerpt

I am using this snippet

```
<a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>' title='<?php echo strip_tags(the_excerpt()); ?>
```

with which I am intending to remove all `ellipses`, `<p>` tags and other `shortcodes` and `links`, but that does not work at all.

If I hover the anchor, I am still getting to see the `<p>` wrapped in the excerpt, as well as other tags and the url links. What am I doing wrong and what do I have to do to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`the_excerpt()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) automatically `echo`es the excerpt text.  What you need is [`get_the_excerpt()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt):

```
<a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>' title='<?php echo strip_tags( get_the_excerpt() ); ?>'>
```

However, it probably won't strip out ellipses (…) since they're HTML entities, not tags.

Comment: For what I know, `get_the_excerpt` is deprecated, but I wil give it a try.

Comment: `get_the_excerpt()` itself doesn't look to be deprecated.  What *is* deprecated is passing it an argument.  (Presumably, in an earlier version of WordPress, you could pass a variable to `get_the_excerpt()`, but that's no longer recommended.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Pat J's answer above you should pass the result through:

[esc_attr()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr)

as well to make sure you have a well-formed attribute value.